# Exibir somente resultados que satisfazerem a condição dentro do laço

Tags: java, loop, arraylist

Estou construindo um pequeno algoritmo que percorre um `ArrayList` e compara o valor encontrado com um valor digitado pelo usuário.

Mas eu quero que seja impresso na tela só o valor que satisfaz a operação, e não os outros valores que não sejam correspondentes aos que foram comparados:

```
   public class Hash {

HashMap<String, String> mapaPosicoes = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> listaPosicoes = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

String posicaoJogador, nomeJogador;

public void pegaDadosJogador() {
    System.out.print("Digite a posição do jogador: ");
    posicaoJogador = teclado.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Digite o nome do jogador: ");
    nomeJogador = teclado.nextLine();
}

public void validadorDadosJogador() {
    listaPosicoes.add("Atacante");
    listaPosicoes.add("Cortador");
    listaPosicoes.add("Levantador");
    listaPosicoes.add("Bloqueador");
    listaPosicoes.add("Jogador de Defesa");
    listaPosicoes.add("Líbero");

    for(String iteracao: listaPosicoes) {
        if(!(!iteracao.equals(posicaoJogador) || nomeJogador.isEmpty())) {
            mapaPosicoes.put(nomeJogador, posicaoJogador);
            System.out.println("Jogador(es) Mapeado(s)");
            System.out.println(mapaPosicoes);
        }else {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }
}
```

public class Execucao {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hash time = new Hash();
    time.pegaDadosJogador();
    time.validadorDadosJogador();
}
```

Observem, ele vai ficar escrevendo **"Entrada não satisfaz"** até encontrar a posição correta no **array**. Eu tenho plena consciência de que isso é culpa do laço, que vai ficar executando até a ultima posição, mas como a variável iteracao é local, não sei como fazer fora do laço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não ficou muito claro pra mim em quais ocasiões a "entrada satisfaz", mas partindo apenas do que fez, creio que da pra eliminar a zaida de dados não desejada apenas negando a condição dentro do if:

```
for(String iteracao: listaPosicoes) {
    if(!(!iteracao.equals(posicaoJogador) || nomeJogador.isEmpty())) {
        System.out.println("Entrada satisfaz");
    }
}
```

Quando a condição dentro do if for verdadeira, significa que ela não satisfaz, então, ao negar o resultado, eu faço com que o if receba true e exiba o texto desejado, ou o que for que você pretenda exibir **somente** quando a entrada for válida.

Somente com a alteração que sugeri, já evita de ficar exibindo várias vezes entradas não validas, mas se quiser exibir caso nada atenda a condição do if, você pode utilizar um contador, que pode servir no futuro caso queira saber quantas entradas forem válidas. Se apenas uma for valida sempre ou não for precisar de contador, então pode utilizar uma variável do tipo `boolean`, apenas pra verificar fora do laço quando for encontrado algo:

```
boolean achou =  false;

...

for(String iteracao: listaPosicoes) {
    if(!(!iteracao.equals(posicaoJogador) || nomeJogador.isEmpty())) {
        mapaPosicoes.put(nomeJogador, posicaoJogador);
        System.out.println("Jogador(es) Mapeado(s)");
        System.out.println(mapaPosicoes);
        achou = true;
    }
}

...

if(!achou) {
    System.out.println("Nenhuma das entradas satisfaz");
}
```

Comment: Realmente deu certo com esse truque da variável boolean, das próximas vezes irei me atentar a esses detalhes de uso da plataforma, obrigado!